# how to install librapidxml-dev by apt-get

Tags: apt

I am currently trying to install librapidxml-dev by simple

```
sudo apt-get install librapidxml-dev
```

But can't seem to get it installed.

```
E: Unable to locate package librapidxml-dev
```

I've tried updating and upgrading aswell.. same response.. 
I would like to avoid manually downloading it and installing, to avoid manually depending it to my project.

Currently running Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: This package is only available for 16.04+. If you are still on 14.04 (or 12.04), take it as a good opportunity to upgrade.

Comment: I am on 14.04... So... What alternatives do i have besides upgrading it..
It has been possible to install it before, why not now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`librapidxml-dev` is only available in the official repositories for Ubuntu 16.04 and later. However, since it does not depend on anything, installing the 16.04 package on 14.04 should be fine. You can get it from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/librapidxml-dev).